# Eager load a directory in development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

According to http://blog.arkency.com/2014/11/dont-forget-about-eager-load-when-extending-autoload/ I know I can use `config.paths.add "extras", eager_load: true` to eager load a directory in production.

However for a `[rails_root]/app/decorators` directory, I need all files under it to be eager loaded even in development environment.

Is there a Rails way to do that? I also need to do that in a gem.

---

To go into more detail, my problem is that my gem provides a BaseDecorator class:

```
class BaseDecorator
  ### Extend corresponding model
  def self.inherited(subclass)
    subclass.model_class.class_eval do
      define_method(:decorator) do
        @_decorator ||= subclass.new(self)
      end
    end
  end

  def self.model_class
    self.name.sub('Decorator','').constantize
  end
end
```

User will inherit this class (e.g. `TopicDecorator`). When they do, I'll automatically create a `decorator()` to `Topic` model which would link to a new `TopicDecorator` instance.

However this means `TopicDecorator` must be eager loaded, otherwise a model would not have that `decorator()` method available.

My intent was that model should not know that its decorator exists. Decorator will do the job of extending model.

I just thought this implementation should be easy and need less computation. However there are probably ways around this.

Comment: Hi, the author of mentioned blog post here. Why do you need to load files from your app in a gem? That's an interesting problem but suggest possible mismatch in a solution. Usually, it is your app that use the gems as libraries. Why would your gem need to load code from an app?

And additional questions, wouldn't it be better to pass those decorators to the gem as dependencies instead of loading them directly from the gem?

Comment: @RobertPankowecki thanks. I have added my use case :)